# DispatcherServlet not injected into the controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, inversion-of-control

I'm developing an application which is run both on Spring Boot (with no web.xml) and on WebSphere (with web.xml). There is a controller which needs to have DispatcherServlet injected into it. While it works on spring boot environment this fails on WebSphere - no bean of type DispatcherServlet can be found.

Down in web.xml i use the parent context (Context Loader Listener) with middle-tier and several dispatchers having their separate contexts. One of them contains such controller (among others).

Why it's not working? My first assumption is that Spring Boot first creates and registers the DispatcherServlet and then scans for controllers while when running with web.xml it happens in reversed order so Controllers are instantiated before DispatcherServlet is accessible from the context.

How can I tackle this problem?

Comment: Pardon me asking, but why do you need to inject DispatcherServlet into a controller?

Comment: For batch processing.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on that?

Comment: Yeah but that's not related to my question. What I'm asking is how can I get the instance of DispatcherServlet in my controller.

Comment: I am asking because I suspect that we are looking at an XY problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: You're right but in this particular case everything's working fine except this one simple thing - which doesn't work only in some scenario and works great in all the others :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not inject DispatcherServlet directly because it is not registered in Spring Context (XmlWebApplicationContext for example). 
But you can extend DispatcherServlet, store link to itself to static field (in constuctor invocation). And you this link anywhere in your code.

Other way - if you create DispatcherServlet "manually" - you can register your DispatcherServlet as bean in application-context.xml.